# Array of integers is unimodal, if: it is strictly increasing in the beginning; after that it is constant; after that it is strictly decreasing

Tags: python, python-3.x

The first block (increasing) and the last block (decreasing) may be absent. It is allowed that both of this blocks are absent.

For example, the following three arrays are unimodal: [5, 7, 11, 11, 2, 1], [4, 4, 2], [7], but the following three are not unimodal: [5, 5, 6, 6, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2], [4, 5, 5, 6].

Write a program that checks if an array is unimodal.

Input
The first line contains integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100) — the number of elements in the array.

The second line contains n integers a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 1 000) — the elements of the array.

Output
Print "YES" if the given array is unimodal. Otherwise, print "NO".

I have written my code it is getting error,
I am getting error in test 8

```
n=int(input())

a=list(map(int,input().split()))

x=a.index(max(a))

p1=(a[:x])
p2=(a[x:])

if ((p1==sorted(p1))and (p2 == sorted(p2,reverse = True))) and x!=len(a)-1:

  print(" YES")
elif n==1 :

  print("YES")
else:

  print("NO")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please paste the full error

Comment: I have mentioned error